# How to create a Cumulative Revenue Graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, plotnine

I am trying to display the cumulative average revenue for each year my customers did a transaction, based on the Year the customers were onboarded (first transaction).

I think I need to use `groupby` but I figure out the best way to achieve the desired result. I have an **example plot** that I wish to replicate or (get something similar):

[image]

Each line on the plot represents the 'Year Onboarded'.

I have created a **toy data** to make it easier:

```
dataset = {'ClientId': [10,20,20,20,10,5,3,7,5,20,12,5],
           'Year Onboarded': [2019,2017,2018,2017,2020,2019,2017,2018,2019,2020,2018,2017],
           'Year': [2020,2018,2018,2017,2020,2020,2018,2019,2020,2020,2018,2019],
           'Revenue': [100,50,25,30,40,50,200,600,20,40,100,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
```

Comment: Is your question about preparing the data, or how to generate a plot?

Comment: It's more about preparing the data, the graph should be fine afterwards

Comment: To me it makes not much sense that the client 10 was onboarded on year 2020 but made revenue on 2019 (?). Perhaps your toy dataset needs a review or I didn't get the problem correctly.

Comment: @Jzbach You're right, I fixed it

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct (since the toy data still shows some inconsistency, i.e. shouldn't the "Year Onboarding" be the same for a given customer?), you are looking for something on the lines of:

`df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['ClientId', 'Year']).Revenue.transform('cumsum')`

And this would yield:

[image: result]